# Why is firebaseConfig not picked up in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/adding-firebase) to add Firebase auth to an appengine app. It works except I always get the warning as if `(typeof firebase === 'undefined')` in `index.html` is always true. I may have put something in the wrong place (noob at web stuff). Here is what I have done (I have removed some comments and the msgbox display code):

```
  <script>
    if (typeof firebase === 'undefined') {
      const msg = "Please paste the Firebase initialization snippet into index.html. See ...";}
  </script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.5.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.5.0/firebase-ui-auth.css">

  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

</head>
<body>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    <script>
      var firebaseConfig = {
       the secrets from firebase which work          };
      the rest is verbatim from the example
```

I have tried putting `firebaseConfig` in the header, same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firebase` won't have a value until after you include firebase-app.js.  Right now, you are checking it before the inclusion.  The order matters a lot.  Just move the scripts above the code that uses them.

Also, the versions of your firebase scripts need to match exactly - what you show right now have version conflicts.

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script>
    if (typeof firebase === 'undefined') {
      const msg = "Please paste the Firebase initialization snippet into index.html. See ...";}

// now you can call firebase.initializeApp()

</script>
```